# Optional Params in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to use optional param for a specific route. Here is what I am trying:

```
<Route name="Products" path="Products/:categoryParam(?:helperParams)" component={ProductListing} />
```

When I send request to http://localhost:3000/Products/Bus?p=2,  it gives me following response:

```
categoryParam: Bus
helperParams: undefined
```

But If replace **?** with **/**, that is, `<Route name="Products" path="Products/:categoryParam(?:helperParams)" component={ProductListing} />` and send request to http://localhost:3000/Products/Bus?p=2. It gives me correct answer.

```
categoryParam: Bus
helperParams: p=2
```

Comment: I think you should change to `path="Products/:categoryParam"` and that way to access the helperParams use the `props.location.query.p` or `props.params.p`

Comment: @FarzadYZ could you please elaborate this thing?

Comment: Optional parameters in react-router are a way to identify parts of URL like `/Products/:category/(:id)` but using query params there is no need to define them inside router configuration as they could be dynamically accessed via `this.props.location.query[paramName]` or `this.props.params[paraName]` and this props are automatically passed through your containers and components

Comment: Still not working. I'm trying to access props.params.p. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Well provide a working demo of your project so that I could help more

Comment: You will need the `?` but I believe you should put it after the expression. So if you use `/Products/:category/(:id)?` React-router uses `path-to-regexp` so you can also look through their documentation or build a same tester that will tell you if it is working or not.